# Asp.net вернуть данные в модель по id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Я пытаюсь вернуть название всех статей, написанных залогиненным пользователем. Какой linq запрос мне для этого нужен? Пока я дошел до этого и метод `GetArticles` выдает ошибку.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Article model = new Article();
     string s = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    if (s != null)
    {
        var user = s;

        model.Text= GetArcticles(user);
    }
    return View(model);
}
private string GetArcticles(string user)
{
    return (from a in db.Articles.Where(c => c.UserId == user)
            select a.Name.SingleOrDefault()).ToString();
}
```

Структура таблицы Articles

```
public class Article
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }


    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}
```

**EDIT:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Article model = new Article();
    List<string> modelText = new List<string>();
    string s = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    if (s != null)
    {
        var user = s;
        modelText = GetArcticles(user);
        foreach (string tmp in modelText)
        {
            model.Text = tmp;
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Думаю стоит показать структуру таблиц.. c.UserId -- тип стринг? Если да то зачем `s.ToString();` если нет то как вы string== не string.

Comment: Укажите ошибку которую вы получаете!

Comment: Теперь хотел уточнить вы говорите , что хотите получить список статей а достаете только `SingleOrDefault()` может быть должен быть `tolist()` или что то не так в описании? ( обращаю внимание что `SingleOrDefault()` "Возвращает единственный элемент последовательности или значение по умолчанию, если последовательность пуста; если в последовательности более одного элемента, генерируется исключение.")

Comment: Я хочу получить список статей для одного автора. Я не совсем понимаю а) как мне его получить из таблицы данных б) как мне его потом добавить в модель, потому что, как я понял, пока в модель будет заноситься только последнее текущее название

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в методе

```
private string GetArcticles(string user)
{
    return (from a in db.Articles.Where(c => c.UserId == user)
            select a.Name.SingleOrDefault()).ToString();
}
```

`SingleOrDefault` применяется к полю `Name`, которое является строкой. Поэтому если в имени больше одно символа вы получаете ошибку.

Чтобы избежать этого постарайтесь не перемешивать `clause syntax` и функции.

Например

```
private string GetArcticles(string user)
{
    return (from a in db.Articles
            where a.UserId == user
            select a.Name)
           .SingleOrDefault().ToString();
}
```